# Delete Starting Even Numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

This function will repeatedly remove the first element of a list until it finds an ***odd number*** or ***runs out of elements***. It will accept a list of numbers as an input parameter and return the modified list where any ***even numbers*** at the beginning of the list are removed. To do this, we will need the following steps:

1. Define our function to accept a single input parameter **`my_list`** which is a list of numbers
2. Loop through every number in the list if there are still numbers in the list and if we haven’t hit an ***odd number*** yet
3. Within the loop, if the first number in the list is ***even***, then remove the first number of the list
4. Once we hit an ***odd number*** or we run out of numbers, return the modified list

I wrote a function called **`delete_starting_evens()`** that has a parameter named **`my_list`**.

The function should remove elements from the front of **`my_list`** until the front of the list is not ***even***. The function should then return **`my_list`**.

For example, if **`my_list`** started as **`[4, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15]`**, then **`delete_starting_evens(my_list)`** should return **`[11, 12, 15]`**.

My code:

```
def delete_starting_evens(my_list):
    for i in my_list:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            my_list.remove(i)
        else:
            break
    return my_list
a=[4,8,10,12,14,15,16,17,19,20]
print(delete_starting_evens(a))
```

The problem is that the function was removing the **even indexes.** I was expecting that the function should delete the ***even numbers*** until it finds the odd number or runs out of elements. How to solve it?

Comment: Don't remove elements from a list as you iterate over it.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I agree, he should probably make a second list maybe

Comment: Just to show the power of Python, a solution with `itertools` from the standard library. You need only one line of code: `a[:] = list(itertools.dropwhile((lambda x: x % 2 == 0), a))`. If it is not necessary to change the original list - as the question suggests - `a = ...` is sufficient.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def delete_starting_evens(my_list):
    idx=-1
    for i in my_list:
        if i % 2 == 1:
            idx = my_list.index(i)
            break
    if(idx==-1):
       return []
    else:
        second_list = my_list[idx:]
        return second_list
a=[4,5,8,10,12]
print(delete_starting_evens(a))
```

Comment: With `for i in my_list`, `i` _is_ a value not an index

Comment: oh yeah, sorry i mistook it for a in range loop. gimme a second I'll change it

Comment: Now the new list only includes odd numbers, which is not what OP wanted. Please test your suggestions before posting them.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I think it's what he wanted now, I'm not sure though

Comment: A couple improvements: 1. Use `enumerate` to get the index and the value in your for loop. That way you don't need to call `my_list.index` because you already have the index of the current item. 2. You don't need to initialize `second_list = []`, since that list is discarded when you do `second_list = my_list[idx:]` anyway.

Comment: Also this fails on a list containing only even numbers, because it returns `my_list[-1:]` in that case.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the failure. However, I first went with enumerate but it showed me an error. As for the second list, you're right : I'd only need to initialize it if my index is different from -1.